# Saving Date to Vector

Tags: r, date, vector

I am running a loop that needs to save a vector to specific column [8]. I am saving different numbers into columns 1...7 of the vector.

But anytime I try it with a date, I get a number instead of date. For instance,

```
> Date_Test <- as.Date("1999-02-02")
> test_me_vector<-vector()
> test_me_vector[1]<-Date_Test
> test_me_vector
```

This returns "10624". How to save a date into a specific column in a vector through vector[8]? Or is there a simple conversion between R date excel-like number and date?

Comment: R is converting the date object to the integer day number from Jan 1, 1970.  Vectors can not store date objects, 'The atomic modes are "logical", "integer", "numeric" (synonym "double"), "complex", "character" and "raw".' See `?vector` for more information.

Comment: Hi @Dave2e, thanks for the info ... is there any way to force the vector to save the date there? Or is there a simple way to convert between number and date in R?

Comment: Two options.  Instead of a vector, use a data frame instead.  Or convert the vector to a date when needed with: `as.Date(x, origin= "1970-01-01")`

Comment: @Dave2e I will apply the second option when I am out of the loop, then. Thanks a lot Dave, helpful indeed!